# Error al intentar importar un dataset: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, vscode, jupyter, tensorflow, dataset

Buen día, tengo un problema y es que quiero importar un dataset Mnist pero al intentar traerlo me genera un error de recursión:

Código:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds



# Descargar conjunto de datos MNIST (Números escritos a mano, etiquetados datos, metadatos)
datos, metadatos = tfds.load('mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
```

---

y este es el error que me genera:

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 7
      2 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
      6 # Descargar conjunto de datos MNIST (Números escritos a mano, etiquetados datos, metadatos)
----> 7 datos, metadatos = tfds.load('mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\logging\__init__.py:168, in _FunctionDecorator.__call__(self, function, instance, args, kwargs)
    166 metadata = self._start_call()
    167 try:
--> 168   return function(*args, **kwargs)
    169 except Exception:
    170   metadata.mark_error()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\load.py:649, in load(name, split, data_dir, batch_size, shuffle_files, download, as_supervised, decoders, read_config, with_info, builder_kwargs, download_and_prepare_kwargs, as_dataset_kwargs, try_gcs)
    530 """Loads the named dataset into a `tf.data.Dataset`.
    531 
    532 `tfds.load` is a convenience method that:
   (...)
    641     Split-specific information is available in `ds_info.splits`.
    642 """
    643 dbuilder = _fetch_builder(
    644     name,
    645     data_dir,
    646     builder_kwargs,
...
--> 130   return self._PATH.join(*self.parts) if self.parts else '.'

File <frozen ntpath>:121, in join(path, *paths)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

Estoy usando python con jupiter en visual studio code

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!!

Comment: Posible issue relacionada en GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/4666. Según los últimos comentarios podrías probar con versiones de Python anteriores a 3.12

Comment: Google usa Python 3.10.12  en colab actualmente, acabo de probar y parece funcionar sin problemas. Si no tienes algún requisito que te obligue a usar versiones superiores podrías probar con la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba aumentar el nivel de recursión permitido. [A alguien le funcionó](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513038/13419694).

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

Comment: buen dia, ya lo intenté de esa manera pero sigue arrojando el mismo resultado.
que otra solucion podria tener?

Comment: @Breiner prueba con un número más grande. El conjunto de datos no dice cómo se debería cargar? Tal vez sugiera cuál número usar.

Comment: he estado probando con un valor mas grande pero sigue igual, me genera el error de que excede la recursion, lo puse tambien en un entorno virtual y lo mismo

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object